# How to write Nested DRF Serializer with two foreign key fields

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Suppose I have Django Models as follows:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    model = models.CharField()
    type = models.CharField()

class Scooter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    model = models.CharField()
    type = models.CharField()

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    car = models.ForeignKeyField()
    scooter = models.ForeignKeyField()
```

and the serializers as follows:

```
class CarSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
    model = Car
    fields = (
        'name',
        'model',
        'type'

    )

class ScooterSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
    model = Scooter
    fields = (
        'name',
        'model',
        'type'

    )


class UservehicleCreateSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    car = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    scooter = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = (
    'name',
    'car',
    'scooter'
    )
```

So the scenario is something like this:
The `car` data and `scooter` data is already created let's assume both have `pk=1`. and I want to create the `User` data using the serializer respectively.
But struggling to find the actual resource for same in my case . The data for car and scooter is already there I need not create it again.

have Tried what's here in [DRF Documentation for writing serialized nested](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

and Data for Api `post request`is as follows:

```
{
    'name': "Nikhil",
    'car': 1,
    'scooter': 1
}
```

Getting error:

```
IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'car_id' cannot be null")
```

Need help on this thing.
Thanks!

Comment: But you haven't got nested data here, so nested serializers is the wrong approach. Your user data contains links to the primary keys of the related models, so you should use the [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield).

Comment: Ok understood this one aspect of my approach(My problem). And when I turned them into the `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` was unable to create data

Comment: So what did you try, and what error did you get?

Comment: @DanielRoseman updated the question

Comment: Why have you set the car and serializer fields to `read_only=True`?

Comment: when removed geting `AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`.`

Comment: Figured out! Thanks @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 5):

Try writing the UservehicleCreateSerializer as follows:

```
class UservehicleCreateSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    car = CarSerializer(read_only=True)
    scooter = ScooterSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
           'name',
           'car',
           'scooter'
        )
```

Output will be like:

```
{
'name': "Nikhil",
'car': [
    'name': "Some name",
    'model': "Some model",
    'type': "Some type"
    ],
'scooter': [
    'name': "Some name",
    'model': "Some model",
    'type': "Some type"
    ]
}
```

I hope this is what you need. Cheers! :)

Comment: No sir I don't need this